# AngularJS Hello:{{test}} page not displaying?

Tags: angularjs

Ok this is my first attempt at this. Trying to get my page to load. my App.js file has all the nessities I hope. here are my  files below:

Index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TodoApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <title>Amazing Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view></div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: 'list.html' }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });

var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.test = "testing";
};
```

List.html:

```
<h1>Hello: {{test}}</h1>
```

I am currently running the Localhost server via Visual Studio 2013. Please Help, Thanks!

Comment: WHat does the console say? There must be some error there

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TodoApp due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: You need to load angular router after angular (ordering of scripts). How can a library load before loading what it is dependent upon. Angular.js is the core right, for any angular components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to include `ngRoute` inorder to use angular routing. So include `ngRoute` in your module as a dependency.

```
 var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]).
        config(.....
```

Also remember to include `angular-route.js` unless you are using very old version of angular that comes with routing as well. You can refer to the cdn [http://code.angularjs.org/x.y.z/angular-route.js](http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular-route.js) or download the file.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HAhyij6o6uKdyv7FcXri?p=preview)**

Comment: TypeError: can't access dead object
 

Filtered chrome url chrome://firebug/content/html/htmlPanel.js

Comment: @testernick79 You would need to download and refer to routing file as well. Please see my answer update

Comment: I'm getting the same results. I updated my index.html and app.js files

Comment: See my demo link, and follow the same steps. It works in the demo. Click on the `Plnkr` link. As a side note- **You would need to start looking at the console errors and understanding what that means.**

Comment: I see it working on the PLNKR site. I even took my code and created my own, it works there too. Do you have any idea if there is a problem running this on a local host via Visual Studio. I'm seriously stumped in this.

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue unless you are missing something obvious. What error do you see in the console? are you sure the script files are loaded properly without any 404

Comment: TypeError: can't access dead object
Filtered chrome url chrome://firebug/content/html/htmlPanel.jsaId is undefined
 

return (aId.startsWith(kSpecialWidgetPfx) || There is a lot more though I cant fit it here.

Comment: Seems like issue with some plugin or something, this seems unrelate but causing the issue in your case